# Check element has class in angular5

Tags: javascript, angular

is there any way to check an element has a class for eg in angular1

```
angular.element(myElement).hasClass('my-class');
```

How can I achieve the same in angular5

Comment: What is wrong with using Element.classList?

Comment: `someElement.classList.contains('foo')` does it for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an example on how to so this:

```
import {Component, NgModule, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div class="bar" #myDiv>Div with a class</div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('has class foo', this.myDiv.nativeElement.classList.contains('foo')) //false
    console.log('has class bar', this.myDiv.nativeElement.classList.contains('bar')) //true
  }
}
```

As you can see from the code, you annotate the element you need to reference with a #{name} and then use ViewChild() in your template to reference it. In ngOnInit, you can access the nativeElement on the ViewChild and with basic DOM querying you can find out if the class is there.

Comment: It's an old thread but for the record this.myDiv should not be used on ngOnInit(). It will be initialized on ngAfterViewInit()